# ELF file .text section disappear after setting -Ttext with certain address

Tags: assembly, linker, elf, bootloader, riscv

I am trying to create a RISC-V based ZSBL.
The problem I'm having is that ELF `.text` section disappears as long as the address ends with `0`,  e.g. `0x300000`, `0x3000100`, etc. Why?

When the address is `0x2000000001`, the output of `readelf` has `.text` section.

```
$riscv64-unknown-elf-as -c zsbl_cp_jmp.S -o zsbl_cp_jmp.o  
$riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -Ttext 0x2000000001  -nostdlib zsbl_cp_jmp.o -o zsbl_cp_jmp.elf

There are 7 section headers, starting at offset 0x11e8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        0000002000000001 001001 000003 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 2] .init             PROGBITS        00000000000100b0 0000b0 00004c 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 3] .riscv.attributes RISCV_ATTRIBUTES 0000000000000000 001004 00002e 00      0   0  1
  [ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 001038 000120 18      5   4  8
  [ 5] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 001158 000056 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0011ae 000039 00      0   0  1
```

When the address is `0x2000000000`, the`.text` section disappears.

```
$riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -Ttext 0x2000000000  -nostdlib zsbl_cp_jmp.o -o zsbl_cp_jmp.elf

There are 6 section headers, starting at offset 0x290:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000010078 000078 00004c 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 2] .riscv.attributes RISCV_ATTRIBUTES 0000000000000000 0000c4 00002e 00      0   0  1
  [ 3] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 0000f8 000108 18      4   3  8
  [ 4] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 000200 000056 00      0   0  1
  [ 5] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 000256 000033 00      0   0  1
```

The source code is

```
.section .init

.global _start
_start:
    li      a0, 0x2000010000
    li      a1, 0x2000030000
    li      a2, 0x20000
    li      t0, 0
1:
    bge     t0, a2, 1f
    add     t1, a1, t0
    lb      t1, 0(t1)
    add     t2, a0, t0
    sb      t1, 0(t2)
    addi    t0, t0, 1
    j       1b
1:
    li t3, 0x2000010000
    jr t3
```

Comment: The assembly code you're showing doesn't have a `.text` section.

Comment: It's interesting that specifying an odd address makes a section appear in the linked binary that wasn't present in the `.o` input.  It has a size big enough to get to the next 4-byte alignment boundary, so probably the default linker script ends up emitting some padding.  Like maybe the default linker script mentions `.text` enough that it has to get "optimized away" if empty.

Comment: @ErikEidt  In my understanding, if you set `-Ttext`, the `.text` section will appear. Is this understanding correct? If it's not correct, how can we explain why `.text` section appears when the address is an odd number？e.g. `0x2000000001`

Comment: Maybe try putting a non-zero length `.text` section in the input and let us know what happens.

Comment: [guessing] The padding required for the odd address is forcing a size of 3 bytes for the section which would otherwise be empty. With the even address, the empty section is eliminated. Perhaps this is what @PeterCordes already said.

Comment: @ranga: yeah, that's what I was thinking.  Like that if something in the linker script wants the *end* of the .text section to be aligned by 4 (so something else can start there? like .init in this case), then as you put it, making it start at an odd address could result in it being non-zero size.  Where normally the linker script does introduce a `.text` even if one doesn't exist in the inputs, but then is able to eliminate it again if its size is zero.